# Subquery joining same table

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

So i have an employees table:

[image]

I'm trying to create a query that displays all the info of this employee but i'm a little stumped at the Employee_Reports_To bit. What i want to appear is the First_Name and Last_Name of the Employee_ID that's stored in this column (Eg Joe Bloggs ID 1, reports to employee Joanne Blog ID 50)

Would this need a join or just a simple select. The database is having issues with the link when i try..

```
SELECT employee.*, departments.Department_Name, 
            jobTitle.Job_Title,
            (SELECT manager.First_Name, manager.Last_Name
                FROM Employee manager
                INNER JOIN employee AS employeeReportsTo
          ON manager.Employee_Reports_To = manager.Employee_ID   
            ) AS Reports_To
            FROM Employee employee
            LEFT JOIN Departments AS departments
                ON departments.Departments_ID = employee.Departments_ID
            LEFT JOIN Job_Title AS jobTitle
                ON jobTitle.Job_Title_ID = employee.Job_Title_ID
             ORDER BY `employee`.`Record_Active` DESC,
                     `employee`.`First_Name` ASC
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT emp.*,
       manager.First_Name, 
       manager.Last_Name,
       departments.Department_Name, 
       jobTitle.Job_Title
FROM Employee emp
INNER JOIN Employee manager
ON emp.Employee_Reports_To = manager.Employee_ID
LEFT JOIN Departments AS departments
ON departments.Departments_ID = emp.Departments_ID
LEFT JOIN Job_Title AS jobTitle
ON jobTitle.Job_Title_ID = emp.Job_Title_ID
ORDER BY emp.Record_Active DESC,
             emp.First_Name ASC
```

It's always better to use `Join` instead of using `Sub Query`.

**EDITED:**

Since column `Employee_Reports_To` can be `null` so it's better to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. Like This:

```
SELECT emp.*,
           manager.First_Name, 
           manager.Last_Name,
           departments.Department_Name, 
           jobTitle.Job_Title
FROM Employee emp
LEFT JOIN Employee manager                     --Changed Join here
ON emp.Employee_Reports_To = manager.Employee_ID
LEFT JOIN Departments AS departments
ON departments.Departments_ID = emp.Departments_ID
LEFT JOIN Job_Title AS jobTitle
ON jobTitle.Job_Title_ID = emp.Job_Title_ID
ORDER BY emp.Record_Active DESC,
         emp.First_Name ASC
```

Comment: I've got it as a join instead of a subquery, however it only displays data if the Employee_Reports_To column has a value in it (so it's missing out like 120 records). The isnull wrap didnt seem to work either, is this because of the join?

Comment: @AisRuss Yes it is because of `INNER JOIN`, in your case use `LEFT JOIN`. I edited my solution have a look and tell me did it solved your problem.

Comment: Thankyou so much! I was racking my brain trying to figure out what was causing it, but that fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your code you could use two time Employee (with alias e1 and e2)  one for employee  and one for the related  manager

```
SELECT e1.*
  , departments.Department_Name
  , jobTitle.Job_Title
  , e2.First_Name
  ,e2.Last_Name
  FROM Employee e1
  INNER JOIN Employee e2 ON e1.Employee_Reports_To = e2.Employee_ID
  LEFT JOIN Departments AS departments
      ON departments.Departments_ID = e1.Departments_ID
  LEFT JOIN Job_Title AS jobTitle
      ON jobTitle.Job_Title_ID = e1.Job_Title_ID
   ORDER BY e1.`Record_Active` DESC,
           e1.`First_Name` ASC
```

Comment: Oh my goodness i didnt realise it was that simple! Thankyou!!